# Angular JS directive "@" $scope in-$digestion

Tags: unit-testing, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Given:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            classToAdd: '@'
        },
        template:
        '<div class="{{classToAdd}}"></div>'
    };
});
```

I'm testing a spec where `classToAdd` is being statically coded in the template:

```
<my-directive class-to-add="foo"></my-directive>
```

and the `classToAdd` attribute is only being recognized if I `$digest` `$rootScope`, and not `$scope`.

Why this is the case?

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yangmillstheory/5Unjg/4/)

Comment: I happen to love the title, by the way. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the shown fiddle was failing, is that "foo" is bound to the `$rootScope`, not the local `$scope`.

The solution is to set the scope variable, interpolate it using `{{foo}}` (since we're using `"@"` in the isolate scope)

```
it('should bind to the class-to-add attribute when we $digest $scope', function () {
    // Arrange
    template = '<my-directive class-to-add="{{foo}}"></my-directive>';
    compiledDirective = $compile(template)($scope);
    directiveEl = compiledDirective.find('div');
    $scope.foo = "bar"

    // Act
    $scope.$digest();

    // Assert
    expect(directiveEl.hasClass('bar')).toBe(true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write your code like this:

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('ctrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.myClass="myClass";
}])
.directive('myDirective',function(){
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{ classToAdd: '@' },
        transclude:true,
        replace: true,
        template:'<div class="{{classToAdd}}" ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs){
            console.log(scope);
            console.log(iAttrs);
        }
    }
})
```

and here is a working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bF2zJ/1/)

notice the console for logs  and under the hood stuff.

Comment: Yep, this is basically what I did in my answer. Thank you!